# How to use custom classes with Apache Spark (pyspark)?

Tags: python, apache-spark, python-module, pyspark

I have written a class implementing a classifier in python. I would like to use Apache Spark to parallelize classification of a huge number of datapoints using this classifier.

1. I'm set up using Amazon EC2 on a cluster with 10 slaves, based off an ami that comes with python's Anaconda distribution on it. The ami lets me use IPython Notebook remotely.
2. I've defined the class BoTree in a file call BoTree.py on the master in the folder /root/anaconda/lib/python2.7/ which is where all my python modules are
3. I've checked that I can import and use BoTree.py when running command line spark from the master (I just have to start by writing import BoTree and my class BoTree becomes available
4. I've used spark's /root/spark-ec2/copy-dir.sh script to copy the /python2.7/ directory across my cluster.
5. I've ssh-ed into one of the slaves and tried running ipython there, and was able to import BoTree, so I think the module has been sent across the cluster successfully (I can also see the BoTree.py file in the .../python2.7/ folder)
6. On the master I've checked I can pickle and unpickle a BoTree instance using cPickle, which I understand is pyspark's serializer.

**However**, when I do the following:

```
import BoTree
bo_tree = BoTree.train(data)
rdd = sc.parallelize(keyed_training_points) #create rdd of 10 (integer, (float, float) tuples
rdd = rdd.mapValues(lambda point, bt = bo_tree: bt.classify(point[0], point[1]))
out = rdd.collect()
```

Spark fails with the error (just the relevant bit I think):

```
  File "/root/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 90, in main
    command = pickleSer.loads(command.value)
  File "/root/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 405, in loads
    return cPickle.loads(obj)
ImportError: No module named BoroughTree
```

Can anyone help me? Somewhat desperate...

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Probably the simplest solution is to use `pyFiles` argument when you create `SparkContext`

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext(master, app_name, pyFiles=['/path/to/BoTree.py'])
```

Every file placed there will be shipped to workers and added to `PYTHONPATH`.

If you're working in an interactive mode you have to stop an existing context using `sc.stop()` before you create a new one.

Also make sure that Spark worker is actually using Anaconda distribution and not a default Python interpreter. Based on your description it is most likely the problem. To set `PYSPARK_PYTHON` you can use `conf/spark-env.sh` files.

On a side note copying file to `lib` is a rather messy solution. If you want to avoid pushing files using `pyFiles` I would recommend creating either plain Python package or Conda package and a proper installation. This way you can easily keep track of what is installed, remove unnecessary packages and avoid some hard to debug problems.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm using python interactively, so I can't set up a SparkContext. How do I do the equivalent to pyFiles in this case? I've defined a function that imports sys and then returns sys.executable. I think this is telling me that all my slaves are running Anaconda. However, if I ssh into them I can see that the environment variable PYSPARK_PYTHON is not set. How can I edit the PYTHONPATH on my slaves?

Comment: Actually you can create a SparkContext in an interactive mode. See updated answer for some details about this and the `PYSPARK_PYTHON` variable

Answer (score 11):

Once the SparkContext is acquired, one may also use `addPyFile` to subsequently ship a module to each worker.

```
sc.addPyFile('/path/to/BoTree.py')
```

[pyspark.SparkContext.addPyFile(*path*) documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.addPyFile)

Comment: this is awesome and exactly what I was looking for... cheers.